# How can declare & initialize a property in the same statement?

Tags: c#

This illustrates what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public class GridModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public List<string> LeftValue { get; set; }
    public List<string> LeftValue = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };
    [...]
}
```

but I am getting an obvious "identifier repeated" error.

Is there a syntax for that? Perhaps with a constant or fixed List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize it using backing field:

```
public class GridModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private List<string> leftValue = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };

    public List<string> LeftValue 
    { 
        get
        {
            return leftValue;
        }
        set
        {
            leftValue = value;
        } 
    }

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't initialize a property's backing field when you declare a property.

You'll have to do it in the constructor or simply not use an auto-implemented property, and initialize the backing field directly.

```
public class GridModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private List<string> _leftValue = new List<string> { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };
    public List<string> LeftValue
    {
        get { return _leftValue; }
        set { _leftvValue = value; }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You cannot set `_leftvValue` in a setter when declared `readonly`. Either remove the setter or the identifier.

Comment: Sorry, but shouldn't it also be `new List<string> (new [] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" });` or `(new [] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" }).ToList();`

Comment: No, these are called collection initializers. The compiler will create an "Add" call for each item inside brackets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples at [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx), e.g.

```
private int month = 7;  // Backing store 

public int Month
{
    get
    {
        return month;
    }
}
```